# trackback spotted in multple http errors

Tags: php, apache

```
[Sun May 11 12:24:46 2014] [error] [client private ip] [X_FORWARDED_FOR 27.159.207.165] Path not found: /contact_us_public.php/trackback/, referer: http://www.mydomain.net/contact_us_public.php
```

Does anyone know what this might mean, or what kind of attack is being attempted?

I noticed since friday (day before last) there has been a lot of activity from someone trying to access links with "trackback". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback doesn't really offer much of a reason as to why someone would attempt to access multple times (on different ip's) a trackback.

Ip's:

```
119.92.251.11
27.159.203.125
27.159.210.166
198.52.215.234, 41.178.225.12
198.52.215.234, 182.253.39.13
```

And then this: [Sat May 10 09:46:55 2014] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes

Has anyone else seen anything like this?